# Any SIMPLE way to fetch ALL results from a PL/SQL cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

The second part of the question: How to do the same (get ALL results, without any loops) with SQL*Plus.

I'm writing some PL/SQL scripts to test the data integrity using Jenkins.

I'm having a script like this:

```
declare
temp_data       SOME_PACKAGE.someRefCurFunction; // type: CURSOR
DATA1              NUMBER;
DATA2              NUMBER;
DATA3              SOMETHING.SOMETHING_ELSE%TYPE;

begin
  cursor := SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here);
  LOOP
   FETCH cursor INTO DATA1,DATA2,DATA3;
   EXIT WHEN temp_data%NOTFOUND;
   dbms_output.put_line(DATA1||','||DATA2||','||DATA3);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Relsults look like this:

```
Something1,,Something2
Something3,Something4,Something5
Something6,Something7,Something8
```

Sometimes the results are null, as in the 1st line. It doesnt matter, they should be.

The purpose of this script is simple - to fetch EVERYTHING from the cursor, comma separate the data, and print lines with results.

The example here is simple as hell, but It's just and example. The "Real life" Packages contain sometimes hundreds of variables, processing enormous database tables.

I need it to be as simple as possible.

Is there any method to fetch EVERYTHING from the cursor, comma separate single results if possible, and send it to output? The final output in the Jenkins test should be a text file, to be able to diff it with other results.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's pretty simple already.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little what's wrong with your current implementation? (beside not [quoting values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization) -- but this is probably not necessary given your data, or is it?)

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - it is. But we need a faster method to produce configuration files and simple SQL*Plus queries. We have to test dozens of PL/SQL packages with almost limitless set of parameters. Writing every query, which will be few times more complicated than the example I've provided, or far more complicated - is too expensive ;)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - the implementation is not wrong, it's correct FWIK.

The result I need is: A SQL*Plus query doing the same thing this code above does, without declaring tons of variables. What I need is a text file with the results, so I can compare it to other results with other sets of parameters etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're truly open to a SQL*Plus script, rather than a PL/SQL block

```
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec :rc := SOME_PACKAGE.someFunction('some',parameters,here);
SQL> print rc;
```

should execute the procedure and fetch all the data from your cursor.  You could spool the resulting CSV output to a file using the `spool` command.  Of course, you then may encounter issues where SQL*Plus isn't displaying the data in a clean format because of the linesize or other similar issues-- that may force you to add some additional SQL*Plus formatting commands (i.e. `set linesize`, `column <<column name>> format <<format>>`, etc.)

It's not obvious to me that a SQL*Plus script buys you much over writing some dynamic SQL that generates the PL/SQL script that you posted initially or (if you're on 12c) writing some code that uses `dbms_sql` to fetch data from the cursor that is returned.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check this out cause it's probably what I'm looking for! Brilliant! I'll let You know if it worked!

Comment: works as a charm, but the problems with formatting the results are overwhelming ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems obvious. You currently have a function which returns a cursor itself returning a data set of hundreds (tho you show only three) fields. You want instead a single string with the comma-separated values. So change the function or write another one based on the same query.

```
package body SOME_PACKAGE
...
-- The current function
function someFunction ...
  returns ref_cursor ...
  -- create cursor based on:
  select f1, f2, f3 --> Three (or n) fields
  from ...
  where ...;
  return generated_cursor;
end function;

-- The new function
function someOtherFunction ...
  returns ref_cursor ...
  -- create cursor based on:
  select f1 || ',' || f2 || ',' || f3 as StringField --> one string field
  from ...
  where ...;
  return generated_cursor;
end function;
end package;
```

This isn't quite all that you asked for. It does save declaring variables (one instead of hundreds) to read the data in one row at a time, but you still read it in one row at a time instead of, as I read your question, reading in every row in one operation. But if such a super-fetch were possible, it would require massive amounts of memory. Sometimes we do things that just require massive amounts of memory and we just work with that the best we can. But your "requirement" seems to be only a matter of convenience for the developers. That, imnsho, lies way down in the list of priorities for consuming resources.

Developing a cursor that returns the data in the final form you want would seem to me to the best of all alternatives.